# How to import another form? Not using visual studio

Tags: vb.net

So first thing, I'm not able to use Visual Studio as I am in Linux, and this is a school project thing. I can't switch to Windows too for some reason. Anyway, I'm trying to import one class to another (I really want it to be a module but doesn't work either). Like the way in python if you have one python program you can just import it on the other one. But somehow it doesn't work, is there a way to do this without using Visual Studio?

Comment: [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/download) and [MonoDevelop](https://www.monodevelop.com/download/) are available for major distributions of Linux.

Comment: Can I do the drag and drop interface with VSC? I am not pretty knowledgeable about it.